# Git issues after MacOS Catalina Upgrade

Tags: xcode, git, macos, macos-catalina

Just upgraded my Mac to Catalina and any `git` command throws this error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSFont._fFlags
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDocumentation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDocumentation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
git: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
git: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch
```

Can I make Git not dependent on Xcode? I rarely use it. Alternatives?

Comment: Not at all sure this will help but, if you launch Xcode, does it ask to download some supporting resources?

Comment: You could install it through Homebrew. I'm not sure I think this is a programming question. This sort of thing belongs on Ask Different (and has been answered there).

Comment: @PhillipMills I believe the implication is the OP has no Xcode and doesn't want to have to have one.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197945/installing-git-on-osx-10-8-without-xcode/197949

Comment: Xcode is messed up with this upgrade: `Xcode cannot be opened because of a problem. Check with the developer to make sure Xcode works with this version of macOS`, likely needs re-install, since this might affect other apps. I'll try HomeBrew option as well. Thanks all.

Comment: @matt If the OP had no Xcode, the "Referenced from" part of the error message wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @PhillipMills Excellent point